# Use Variable in Eloquent whereIn Clause

Tags: php, eloquent, where-clause

whats the right way to use a variable in eloquent whereIn Clause?

For example this is my string variable

```
$testVar = 'Dave, Tom, Brad';
```

And here is my eloquent Query.

```
$spielerArray = Spieler::join('PlanungSpieler', 'PlanungSpieler.Player_ID', '=', 'Spieler.Player_ID')
            ->whereIn('Spieler.Name', [$testVar])
            ->get();
```

When I put this $testVar into the Query I get back an empty result. But this is not correct. Because I have the values Dave Tom and Brad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case   `$testVar` is string then you have to convert to array

```
 $testVar = 'Dave, Tom, Brad';
    $myArray = explode(',', $testVar);
```

after thay you can pass  `$myArray` into `whereIn`

```
  $spielerArray = Spieler::join('PlanungSpieler', 'PlanungSpieler.Player_ID', '=', 'Spieler.Player_ID')
                ->whereIn('Spieler.Name', $myArray )
                ->get();
```

Comment: maybe with `$myArray = array_map('trim', $myArray);` or explode with `, `